# TFS and Redmine integration

Tags: tfs, redmine

What is the best way to integrate TFS with Redmine?

When creating or modifying a work item on TFS we want it to be replicated on Redmine.

Answer (score 0):

There is not any official plugins or something similar for combining TFS and  Redmine.

However you could use some 3-party tool such as  [Cloudpipes](https://www.cloudpipes.com/) to integrate Redmine with Team Foundation Server.